# atoi() Not Working with std::string::substr()

Tags: c++, string, atoi

This is a snippet of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h> // atoi()


int main() {

    std::string line;

    std::ifstream numbers("numbertest.txt");

    if (numbers.is_open()) {
        while (std::getline(numbers, line)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length() - 4; i++) {
                for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
                    std::cout << atoi((line.substr(i, 5)[n]).c_str());
                }
```

I want to operate with numbers in groups of 5, from a file. Why is atoi() not working here? It says "expression must have class type" under the second parentheses on the atoi line.

Comment: `line.substr(i, 5)` returns a substring of 5 characters in `line` from position `i` - so `foo = "hello world"; foo.substr(2, 5);` would produce "llo wo". the `[n]` operator returns the nth character of that substring. atoi expects a `const char*`, not a `char`.

Comment: @kfsone Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay on my kindle, and trying to write as an answer with a code example was just a bit much for this time of the night :)

Comment: Do not use `atoi`! It's one of those evil `errno` based functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `atoi( line.substr(i,5).c_str() )`

Or if you want for each character

```
std::cout << ((line.substr(i, 5)[n]) - '0');
```

Or even better

```
std::cout << (line[i+n]) - '0');
```

Note that: `atoi` is **not** ascii to integer. It converts a ctype string to number. For a single character, this conversion should be done using arithmetic or lookup table.

Also there is no point converting characters to integer and then print it (back to chacters). You should better print digit character itself.

Moreover in C++, I would prefer to use stringstream instead or atoi. On C++11 there are even more advanced solutions like sto*.

Answer (score 5):

`line.substr(i, 5)` creates a temporary std::string containing 5 characters in `line` from position `i`

```
std::string foo = "hello world";
int i = 2;
std::cout << foo.substr(2, 5) << '\n';
```

would print "llo wo".

The `[n]` operator returns the `n`th character of the substring, which is of type `char`, you are then calling `.c_str()` on that *character* rather than on the substring.

You can avoid the `.c_str()` entirely by using [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), e.g.

```
std::cout << "line.substr(i, 5) = " << line.substr(i, 5) << '\n';
std::cout << std::stoi(line.substr(i, 5));
```

aoti and stoi both take a string representation of a number as their input and return the numeric value. For example:

```
std::string input = "123a";
// std::cout << input * 10 << '\n'; // illegal: input is a string, not a number.
int i = std::stoi(input); // converts to integer representation, i.e. 123
std::cout << i * 10 << '\n'; // outputs 1230
```

----- EDIT -----

You're actually asking all the wrong questions. What you want to do is take an input pattern and output all of the patterns of 5 characters in it.

Example input: "1020304050"
Example output: 10203 02030 20304 03040 30405 04050

You don't need to convert these to numbers to output them, you can just output the characters. The problem with your original code wasn't the conversion it was the incorrect sequence of operators.

`std::substring` is expensive, it has to create a new, temporary string, copy characters from the original into it, and then return it, and it does it for every call.

The following should achieve what you're trying to do:

```
while (std::getline(numbers, line)) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < line.length() - 4; i++) {
        for (size_t n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
            std::cout << line[i + n];
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

If you really want to invoke substr, you could also implement this as

```
while (std::getline(numbers, line)) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < line.length() - 4; i++) {
        std::cout << line.substr(i, 5) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Here's a working demonstration: http://ideone.com/mXv2z5

Comment: There you go. I knew you can do it. ;)

Comment: ;) broke out the laptop.

Comment: Everytime I want to correct you, you already edited your answer. :) +1

Comment: @kfsone How do you convert a part of the substring to an int? Like substr(i,n)[n]. This is what I was asking.

Comment: @Tetramputechture [std::string::substring()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) returns a (temporary) std::string, so you can (a) use `int i = std::stoi(mystr.substr(1, 5));` or (b) `int i = atoi(mystr.substr(i,5).c_str());`. Note that if "mystr" contains "123456", both of these would return an integer with a value of 23456.

Comment: Ok - I was having a hard time understanding what you are asking because that's a terrible thing to do. `substr` has to create a new object and copy n characters from the source string into that string.

Comment: See Edit to my answer.